# Add a slider to plotly that dynamically changes a column of data frame that is displayed

Tags: pandas, plotly, slider

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

A = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
B = [40,50,60,10,20,30]

data = pd.DataFrame({"A":A,"B":B})
alpha=0.5
data["Parameter"]= alpha*data["A"] +(1-alpha)*data["B"]


fig = px.scatter(
    data, x="A",y="B",color="Parameter"
)
fig.show()
```

I would like to have a slider for alpha in plotly graph. I looked at the documentation but only found a slider for a fixed column with constant values.

Comment: In my understanding, all options for your `alpha` will have to be precalculated in order to work with a slider for a single `go.Figure()` object. If you're willing to use `Plotly Dash` or `JupyterDash`, it would be a whole different matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = px.scatter(data, x="A", y="B", color="Parameter", animation_frame='Parameter')
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus")
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 100])
fig.show('browser')
```